# How does the Doctor exit the TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

How does the Doctor exit the TARDIS? Is there an exit door? What does it look like? How do you open it?

Comment: I suspect that the downvoters are wondering, as I am, how you can have missed this if you've ever actually watched _Doctor Who_.  It's on screen quite often.  In fact, you've prompted the perhaps far more interesting question of whether there is any serial (or standalone episode) during which **no** character has left or entered the TARDIS on-screen.  Even the third Doctor (or Jo) managed to have reasons to enter/exit the TARDIS.

Comment: @JdeBP ["The Edge of Destruction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Edge_of_Destruction)

Comment: Reopened. To my chagrin, "[General Reference](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference)" is no longer an acceptable close reason.

Comment: It's unclear what misconception you have about the tardis. We can re-open this when you can specify why this is not trivial. Clearly we're missing something.

Comment: @JdeBP Most episodes aired between 1963 and 1989 didn't include the TARDIS. Typically, the Doctor exited it in episode 1, then spent several episodes fighting some monster, and re-entered it only in the final episode. It was thus seen in, on average, only 2 episodes of each 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8 part serial. In the Pertwee years, whole serials went by (sometimes entire seasons, e.g. season 7) in which it never appeared at all (for example _The Silurians_, _Ambassadors of Death_, _Inferno_, _The Daemons_, _Day of the Daleks_, etc). Pertwee and Tom Baker had no TARDIS scenes in their whole 1st season.

Answer (score 7):

The Doctor typically exits the TARDIS through the [main door](http://www.whoniverse.net/tardis/maindoors).

[image]

There also appears to be a secondary exit at the rear of the TARDIS, as seen (or rather not seen, since we're watching the front door when the Doctor emerges from behind the TARDIS) in the classic serial [Logopolis](http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/classic/episodeguide/logopolis/detail.shtml)

Comment: This answer could have been so much better if you actually provided a source (read: picture) for your closing statement.

Comment: @MrLister - Your slightest whim is my heart's fondest desire.

Comment: Hm... Since I haven't memorised all the scenes of that serial, could you indicate when in which ep he does that?

Comment: @MrLister - Logopolis Pt1, timestamp 21:40